# odbcinst symbol lookup error SQLManageDataSources

Tags: linux, sybase, freetds, unixodbc, sqlanywhere

I've just installed unixODBC on Pop-OS (Ubuntu 20 base). there's no odbcinst.ini file, just odbc.ini and when I run odbcinst -j I just get the following

odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: SQLManageDataSources

I'm not an experienced ODBC user. I just have a task to connect to SQL Anywhere DB which is a big enough pain as it is, but from what I can see I need unixODBC up and working and then use freetds as the driver (as other drivers are propriety)

However, unixODBC seems to be busted, or I think it is.

I have unixODBC, unixODBC-dev, pyodbc, freetds, freetds-bin, freetds-dev and SQL Anywhere Developers edition installed

Answer (score 0):

I did a reinstall of unixodbc and freetds and it fixed the problem. SqlManageDataSources appears to be a unixODBC function that obviously installed incorrectly